# Deriving Rayleigh's equation through integration of a Bessel Function

Tags: physics, special-functions, mathematical-physics, bessel-functions

Rayleigh's equation defines the relative intensity in an airy disk diffraction pattern. It is given as 
$$[1]\quad L\left(\beta q_{0}\right)=1-J_{0}^{2}\left(\beta q_{0}\right)-J_{1}^{2}\left(\beta q_{0}\right)$$
I am attempting to derive this expression, but I am stuck on a step involving evaluating a definite integral of a squared Bessel function over x.

When attempting to derive the relation from the expression for the intensity in a diffraction pattern according to Airy-Kirchhoff diffraction theory, I obtain the following expression
$$[2]\quad L\left(\beta q_{0}\right)=\int_{0}^{q_{0}} J_{1}^{2}(\beta q)(d q / q) / \int_{0}^{\infty} J_{1}^{2}(\beta q)(d q / q)$$

This expression is supposed to result in Rayleigh's equation by applying the following relation:

$$[3]\quad\int_{0}^{x_{0}} J_{1}^{2}(x) \frac{d x}{x}=\frac{1}{2}\left[1-J_{0}^{2}\left(x_{0}\right)-J_{1}^{2}\left(x_{0}\right)\right]$$

This is the part I am stuck on. My knowledge of Bessel functions is very limited: I'm vaguely familiar with the integral and infinite series representations of Bessel functions and the differential equation they are a solution to. I have no idea how to approach this integral, and I'd appreciate any clarifications anybody could provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the [recurrence relations](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.6.E2) for the Bessel functions:
\begin{align}
J_{\nu}'\left(z\right)&=J_{\nu-1}\left(z\right)-(\nu/z)
J_{\nu}\left(z\right)\\
&=-J_{\nu+1}\left(z\right)+(\nu/z)
J_{\nu}\left(z\right)
\end{align} 
respectively with $\nu=1$ and $\nu=0$  to obtain the identities
\begin{align}
 \frac{J_1(x)}{x}&=J_0(x)-J'_1(x)\\
 J'_0(x)&=-J_1(x)
\end{align} 
and thus
\begin{align}
 \frac{J_1^2(x)}{x}&=J_0(x)J_1(x)-J_1(x)J'_1(x)\\
 &=-J_0(x)\frac{dJ_0(x)}{dx}-J_1(x)\frac{dJ_1(x)}{dx}\\
 &=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}\left[J_0^2(x)+J_1^2(x)\right]
\end{align} 
Finally, as $J_1(0)=0$ and $J_0(0)=1$,
\begin{equation}
 \int_{0}^{x_{0}} J_{1}^{2}(x) \frac{d x}{x}=\frac{1}{2}\left[1-J_{0}^{2}\left(x_{0}\right)-J_{1}^{2}\left(x_{0}\right)\right]
\end{equation}